# Font.PLAIN Double cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

 Object source = e.getSource();
 if(source == Arial)
    {

     test.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN, 12));
     test.setVisible(true);
     S.setEnabled(true);
     L.setEnabled(true);
     labelFont = test.getFont();

  }
```

I am getting an error in JGrasp the pointer for the error points at the . in between Font.PLAIN. I am not understanding where the issue is or at least i'm not finding it blatantly obvious. I am just learning so it is probably something I just haven't seen before or even more likely something stupid I have done.

the full error is

```
JFontSelector.java:75: error: double cannot be dereferenced
     test.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

Comment: You've either got a double variable named `Font` or one named `test`. Either way, don't try to call a method on a double variable, since that won't work for primitives.

Comment: Note that you're not showing enough of the error message and should show the **entire** message.

Comment: Ok, now I feel a complete Idiot it never dawned on me not to name the variable Font... I'm an idiot but that fixed all errors thank you.

Comment: Yes, as a general rule, you want to avoid giving variables names that might conflict with key core Java class names.